# Is there any way to snapshot entire website to detect changes caused by CSS change?

Tags: html, css, compare, snapshot

I'm maintaining a website where a recent CSS change intended to solve a problem on one page inadvertently caused a problem on another page. I know there are ways to take a snapshot of a single webpage (and by snapshot, I mean get an image of how it looks to the end-user). Is there any way to quickly and easily grab snapshots of every page on a website, so I can make a before-and-after comparison?

Comment: While a good question, I'm not sure if this is on topic for SO.

Comment: Sorry, still new here. What community would be a better fit?

Comment: I'm not sure; maybe [Webmasters](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be more suited. However. The problem is also that his is an open question, you're asking for recommendations, which these sites are not designed for. These are Q&A sites, meant for questions that have one specific answer to each question.